# Swift 3 use optional chaining in map or filter

Tags: swift, swift3

How can I use optional chaining in this line of code

```
let sectionNames:[String] = pois.map({ $0.IconName! })
```

if I write:

```
let sectionNames:[String] = pois.map({ $0?.IconName })
```

I get

> Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Poi'

Poi is an object:

```
   public class Poi {
    public var Id: Int
    public var Name: String?
    public var Latitude: Double?
    public var Longitude: Double?
    public var IconName: String?
  }
```

I want to avoid using '!' wherever I can so I use

```
guard let iconname = poi.IconName else { return }
```

in other parts of the app. 
My question is how to avoid '!' in .filter or .map

Comment: Why do you want optional chaining? What can be nil? Please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: The question has been answered. The trouble is you're not listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `flatMap` (`compactMap` in Swift 4) to filter out nils:

```
let sectionNames = pois.flatMap { $0.IconName }
```

Comment: It was `flatMap` in Swift 3.

Comment: compactMap works fine to filter out nils but how about using optional chaining in filter:
    `let result = pois.filter({$0.IconName! == section.id})`

Comment: @ThomasArnold Any time you say `!` you risk crashing and are thinking about the problem incorrectly.

Comment: @matt You are right and I want to avoid  '!'  but I don't know how, that's the reason I ask

Comment: @ThomasArnold This answer is correct. It solves the problem in the only way that makes any sense. You have declared `sectionNames` as a `[String]`, so it cannot contain `nil`. But Poi's `IconName` might be `nil`. Therefore you call `compactMap` so that no `nil` values wind up in `sectionNames`, while at the same time unwrapping all the Optional String values of `IconName` so that they are String and not `String?`. Try it!

Comment: @ThomasArnold Your comment about using `filter` and optional chaining is very different from your posted question.

Comment: @maddy my question topic was 'use optional chaining in map or filter', or better how can I avoid '!' in 
'pois.filter({$0.IconName! == section.id})'
and 
'pois.map({ $0.IconName! })'
can I write some guard let inside the .filter({}) or .map({})?


'

Comment: @ThomasArnold You don't need any `?` or `!` for that filter. Just do `pois.filter { $0.IconName == section.id }`

Comment: @maddy Life can be so easy, thank you! That solved my problem with the '!'

Answer (score 2):

`pois` is an array of `Poi` not `Poi?`. It's not an array of optionals, so you can't use optional chaining on its elements.